# Выбор технологии и языка для написания диплома

Tags: asp.net-mvc, php, yii, visual-studio, ruby-on-rails

Здравствуйте. Сразу попытался более четко обозначить тему в заголовке. Сразу извиняюсь за неточности, не пинайте, лучше укажите в чем не прав и я скажу вам спасибо.

Может кому покажется странным, но я сейчас уже начал думать о дипломе (закончил 4 курс). По мне не так важна тема, как язык и технологии на котором его писать. Это мне нужно что бы подтянуть свой уровень за лето и осень в выбранном языке.

В качестве темы склоняюсь к информационной системе для веб-студии. Написать такие возможности как добавление и управление проектами, сотрудниками, организация работы, вывод списка задач и т.д.

Есть желание написать андроид-приложение к системе на котором можно к примеру показывать сведения о статусе проекта заказчику.

Это я описал первые мысли и наброски, функционала конечно будет больше.

Теперь собственно к сути вопроса, на чем писать ASP.NET MVC 4 или Yii PHP Framework или Ruby on Rails? Почитал на форумах и статьи об обоих. Приглянулись.

С php немного знаком, с c# намного дольше. Цена на хостинг не влияет на выбор. Visual Studio нравится.

Важно узнать ваше профессиональное мнение с учетом таких показателей:

1. Скорость изучения.
2. Функциональность.
3. Создание api (или через что лучше организовать доступ с сайту через мобильное приложение?) для приложения андроид.
4. Возможность найти помощь по проблемам (другими словами размер лояльного сообщества)
5. Сложность изучения
6. Производительность
7. Подскажите что еще важно при выборе?

Приму любые ответы от "Иди к мамочке школота" до "Чего забыл в программистах?" =)

Надеюсь на ваши помощь.

p.s.: добавил в вопрос еще Ruby on Rails

Comment: @Fike спасибо за здравые мысли "Вопрос только в том, чтобы после диплома не выяснилось, что вместо набора опыта в том языке, с которым хочется работать, был зря набран опыт в другом" 

актуально для меня в плане того что нравиться c#, буду еще думать, не зря этим вопросом занялся за год.

Comment: @klopp согласен, производительность у меня не будет стоять во главе, мне нужен будет функциональный сайт чтобы на защите получить хорошую оценку. Хоть руки у меня и кривые, но на производительность не посмотрят

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[@Колямбий](/users/12184/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B9) в общем, и (надеюсь) многие со мной согласятся, важнее скорее не конкретный язык программирования т.е. инструмент а то как вы им владеете. За годы работы я повидал много проектов - и хороших и не очень написанных на самых разных языках. Не поверите, но порой вещи написанные на VisualBasic 14 лет назад могут поразить своей продуманной архитектурой, а "спагетти" на C#/MVC/ASP.NET заставить плакать от бессилия (и попыток объяснить руководству почему не надо нанимать индусский офшор).
Конечно никто не спорит что одни инструменты лучше подходят под определенные задачи, а другие хуже, но в целом **уровень владения инструментом важнее чем сам инструмент**

Поскольку как вы пишете

> С php *немного* знаком, с c# *намного*
> дольше. Цена на хостинг не влияет на
> выбор. *Visual Studio нравится*.

то, мне кажется, очевидным для вас выбрать C# c ASP.NET и MVC 4(или 5)

1. **Скорость изучения**. Итак, с учетом владения C# а также с бесплатными обучающими видео от Pluralsight на http://www.asp.net/mvc проблем будет не много.
2. **Функциональность**. Имхо, мне ещё не попадалась задача которую нельзя было решить на C# ;-) (Попадались правда те которые элегантнее было бы решить на скритовом языке и те для решения которых в других языках были встроенные функции)
3. **Создание api** В MVC 4 из коробки вы получаете отличный инструмент для построения API о чём вы можете прочитать тут [build restful apis with aspnet web api](http://www.asp.net/web-api/tutorials/hands-on-labs/build-restful-apis-with-aspnet-web-api) или [RESTFul Api контроллеры в .NET MVC 4](http://habrahabr.ru/post/164945/)
4. **Возможность найти помощь по проблемам** ну ресурсов не мало - hashcode, StackOverflow, скорее зависит от специфической задачи. В конечном счете есть поисковики и очень редко бывает так, что никто не столкнулся с подобной проблемой до вас.
5. **Сложность изучения** зависит от многих факторов, но в целом от желания и предыдущего опыта. Для меня C# был легче чем VB или C++, а вот с Delphi так и не сложилось. Я уверен что вы сможете найти очень много материалов по C#.
6. **Производительность** с новыми обертками для асинхронности вроде async\await вы может значительно повысить производительность вашего вебсайта если пройдётесь по "долгоиграющим" методам. Однако не будем скрывать что IIS немного "тугодум", но если честно, то большая часть тормозов при работе с сайтами > 4000 пользователей - это не  грамотная работа с БД ну и сама БД. :-)
7. **Подскажите что еще важно при выборе?** Мне кажется важнее всего для вас определиться с тем что вы будете делать *после* диплома :-) в конечном счете кем собираетесь работать, ну и так далее. Мой главный совет - **получайте только те знания которые вам пригодятся в будущем**. Не стоит терять много времени просто на изучение инструментов/технологий. Замечательно иметь широкий кругозор, но важнее быть в чем-то профессионалом. Так что определитесь с направлением и вперед.

P.S. я очень давно работаю с C#, так что, конечно, мой взгляд субъективен имейте это ввиду :-)

Comment: @pvkovalev спасибо за подробный ответ.

"то, мне кажется, очевидным для вас выбрать C# c ASP.NET и MVC 4(или 5)" не нашел доступного хостинга с поддержкой mvc 5

хотел начать изучение с книги "ASP.NET MVC 4 в действии"

"получайте только те знания которые вам пригодятся в будущем" если и буду работать программистом, то только в веб, остальное не привлекает. Но больше хочется заняться управлением проектами и сайтами, предлагать идеи, так как с реализацией хромает у меня пока =((

Comment: @Колямбий на счет хостинга - а пользуюсь http://www.Smarterasp.net/index?r=pvkovalev у них там 60 дней пробный период и в целом всё не плохо. Сравните с http://www.parking.ru/shared/win/ я с ними раньше работал, хостил сайты для клиентов, тоже проблем не возникало. На счет книги я бы порекомендовал Adam Freeman - "Pro ASP.NET MVC 4" но сначала посмотрите видео от Pluralsight. Они помогут вам понять взаимодествие View - Controller и другие аспекты. Чтобы начать не надо знать много, у вас ещё есть время, вы успеете разобраться :-)

Comment: @Колямбий, не хотелось бы Вас обижать, но IMHO "генератор идей", который сам толком не представляет, во что выливается их реализация, мало кому будет нужен.

Comment: @avp так я только хочу (надо хотелку убавить), может и не стану с моим то подходом =)

Comment: >если и буду работать программистом, то только в веб, остальное не привлекает


Ох, порочный подход... "Остальное" - это как раз база для веб-программирования, и без неё никуда, от слова совсем. Потому как веб-программирование - это всё-таки сначала "программирование", а потом уже "веб". Ну и потом, кто знает как жизнь сложится...

Comment: @pvkovalev а как у них с пингом для России, где сервера? спасибо за советы.

Comment: @Колямбий, разработку можно проводить хоть у себя в виртуалке, причем у майкрософта есть такая штука, как [dream spark](http://www.dreamspark.ru/), которой я бы воспользовался.

Comment: @Колямбий а хм.. хороший вопрос, я из России с ними не работал, только с parking.ru

Comment: @pvkovalev а вы могли бы предоставить пожалуйста ссылку на какой-нибудь ваш проект, чтобы потестить пинг? и скажите какие ограничения на у Smarterasp.net на использование процессора и оперативки?

Comment: напишите на лиспе/schema - старикам понравится, или на Haskell - понравится хакерам, смотря кого в комиссии больше.

Answer (score 4):

> нравиться

**нравится**

> Скорость изучения.

Очень быстрая у Yii. Шарп наверняка будет посложней, но это окупится опытом.

> Производительность

C# наверняка порвет.

> Функциональность.

С шарпом в вебе не работал, но у него наверняка гораздо проще с задачами типа обработки бинарных файлов, изображений и прочего.

> Создание api (или через что лучше организовать доступ с сайту через мобильное приложение?) для приложения андроид.

В Yii 2 обещают REST из коробки настолько, насколько это возможно, к НГ может и выйдет в релиз.

**Обновление**

Вообще я бы посмотрел пошире, чем ASP.NET/Yii. Yii позиционируется как легковесное решение, на котором можно *набодяжить чего угодно*, ASP обычно берут для весьма серьезных приложений, где четко расписан план развития (ну, или мне так кажется), в общем, более *энтерпрайзен*. Задачка сама по себ *энтерпрайзна*, и я бы смотрел в сторону Symfony или связки js (ember.js, насколько понимаю, самый популярный выбор для такого) + rest api на laravel. Вопрос только в том, чтобы после диплома не выяснилось, что вместо набора опыта в том языке, с которым хочется работать, был зря набран опыт в другом.

Answer (score 2):

> Написать такие возможности как добавление и управление проектами, сотрудниками, организация работы, вывод списка задач и т.д.

Ну, JIRA и YouTrack вообще на Java написаны, Редмайн - на Ruby :)

**Обновление**

[[@Колямбий](/users/12184/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B9)](/users/12184/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B9), я к тому, что на самом деле не принципиально на чём. См. [здесь, например](http://goo.gl/S6zc5F), на чём только не пишут, и вполне приличные системы получаются. А производительность - не то, во что всё упрётся. Ну на чём там её сажать-то? Разве что на какой-нибудь кривой рассылке по куче адресов, но так это от кривизны рук в любом случае зависит, а не от языка или фреймворка. Поэтому писать имеет смысл на том, что лучше освоится.

Comment: @klopp спасибо за совет, да по описанию Redmine подходит под мои задачи, но с Ruby совсем не знаком, сложен он в изучении? сложно будет дописать что-то свое к Redmine?